# Formatting a table based on Criteria in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset which is generated using this

```
set.seed(1221)
runs<-2
pd<-list()
for(k in 1:runs){
  p<-10
  n_b <- sample(1:6,p,replace = T) 
  bs<-c("S","M","L") 
  cl <- sample(1:3,p,replace= T) 
  Y<-4  
  d_km<-5.5
  cdata<-as.data.frame(matrix(0,p,20))
  for(i in 1:nrow(cdata)){
    cdata[i,1]<-n_b[i]
    for (j in 2:(n_b[i]+1)){
      cdata[i,j] <- rnorm(1,9,2)
    }
    cdata[i,8]<- sum(cdata[i,2:7])
    cdata[i,9]<-cl[i]
    if (cdata[i,9]==1){
      cdata[i,10]=max(0,cdata[i,8]-23)
    }
    else if (cdata[i,9]==2){
      cdata[i,10]=max(0,cdata[i,8]-28)
    }
    else{
      cdata[i,10]=max(0,cdata[i,8]-32)
    }
    cdata [i,11]= cdata[i,10]*Y*d_km
    if (cdata[i,9]==1){
      cdata[i,12]=max(0,cdata[i,1]-2)
    }
    else if (cdata[i,9]==2) {
      cdata[i,12]=max(0,cdata[i,1]-2)
    }
    else {
      cdata[i,12]=max(0,cdata[i,1]-3)
    }
    if (cdata[i,12]>=1){
      cdata[i,13]=sample(bs,1,replace = F)
    }
    else{
      0
    }
    if (cdata[i,12]>=2){
      cdata[i,14]=sample(bs,1,replace = F)
    }
    else{
      0
    }
    if (cdata[i,12]>=3){
      cdata[i,15]=sample(bs,1,replace = F)
    }
    else{
      0
    }
    if (cdata[i,12]>=4){
      cdata[i,16]=sample(bs,1,replace = F)
    }
    else{
      0
    }
    for(j in 13:16){
      if(cdata[i,j]=="S"){
        cdata[i,j+4]=runif(1,115,125)
      }else if(cdata[i,j]=="M"){
        cdata[i,j+4]=runif(1,135,145)
      }else if(cdata[i,j]=="L"){
        cdata[i,j+4]=runif(1,145,158)
      } else {
        cdata[i,j+4]=0
      }
    }
  }
  paxd<-cdata[,c(9,13:16)]
  pd[[k]]<-paxd
}
pdf<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,pd))
pdff<-cbind(day=rep(1:runs,each=p),pdf)
```

I need to formulate table like this shown in the figure attached. [image: This is table need to be generated from the pdff data]. \

The " S", "M", and "L" column will show the calculated number of "S", "M" and "L" for each day and for each class. Basically a count. 
I tried this to filter the data using `dplyr`

```
colnames(pdff)<-c("day","class","B-1","B-2","B-3","B-4")
pdfx<-pdff %>% filter(day==1) %>% filter(class==1)
```

After that I got stuck. Can anyone help using data analysis?

```
dput(pdff)

structure(list(day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), class = c(3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 1), `B-1` = c("0", "L", "S", "S", "S", "S", "L", "M", "0", 
"S", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "S", "S", "0", "S", "L", "S", "M", 
"L", "0", "L", "0", "0", "M", "0", "M", "0", "L", "L", "0", "0", 
"S", "S", "M", "S", "M", "L", "L", "0", "0", "S", "0", "S", "0", 
"S", "0"), `B-2` = c("0", "L", "L", "0", "L", "M", "L", "S", 
"0", "L", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "M", "L", 
"0", "M", "0", "0", "0", "0", "M", "0", "L", "0", "M", "L", "0", 
"0", "0", "S", "M", "0", "L", "S", "S", "0", "0", "S", "0", "0", 
"0", "M", "0"), `B-3` = c("0", "0", "L", "0", "L", "L", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"S", "0", "S", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "L", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "M", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0"), `B-4` = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "S", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"S", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "S", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

Comment: Could you just post the relevant dataset with `dput()` please?

Comment: If you run the code itself the dataset will be generated. pdf is the dataset. I think that will give you the idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get the data in long format, remove rows with 0 values, count number of rows for each `day` and `class` and get data in wide format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pdff %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(day, class)) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(class, value), factor) %>%
  count(day, class, value, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = n)


#  day   class     L     M     S
#  <chr> <fct> <int> <int> <int>
#1 1     1         6     2     4
#2 1     2         2     0     1
#3 1     3         2     0     1
#4 2     1         1     1     1
#5 2     2         0     0     0
#6 2     3         0     0     2
```

Comment: Error: This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet.
i Contact the package author and suggest using `eval_select()`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred

Comment: that is weird, I don't get that error. What package version are you using? Mine is `dplyr` `0.8.5` and `tidyr` `1.0.2`.

Comment: Actually I was first able to get the answer. Now after few runs this error is coming. How to know the package version Ronak?

Comment: `packageVersion('dplyr')` and `packageVersion('tidyr')`

Comment: Same package version I have. Just checked. dplyr is 0.8.5 and tidyr is 1.0.2

Comment: Any other method can you suggest please?

Comment: Please restart R and try again. I don't see why should it give you an error if you are using the same package version.

Comment: Yeah got it now. Thanks a lot Ronak. Only one small request. If you see day 2 there is no class 2 row which should contain S, M, and L as "0". Can you add this?

Comment: Updated the answer to include that.

Comment: Ronak can we merge the day rows to a single row without affecting other columns? I am asking whether it is possible to create a multirow table from that as shown in the image?

Comment: That is actually not R-way of having data but there are packages which allow you to put data in such formats for display purposes. Check `kable` and `formattable` package.